# New adMob not showing interstitial ads in samsung Note-2 having android 4.4.2

Tags: admob, google-play-services, android-4.4-kitkat

I am developing one game and using new Google play service integrated adMob for showing interstitial ad.But the interstitial full screen ads are not showing.I am Testing it on Samsung Note-2.

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Logs...

08-31 12:58:49.735: E/ActivityThread(7398): Pause GC
08-31 12:58:49.735: E/ActivityThread(7398): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-31 12:58:49.735: E/ActivityThread(7398):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-31 12:58:49.735: E/ActivityThread(7398):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-31 12:58:49.735: E/ActivityThread(7398):     at android.app.ActivityThread.pauseGC(ActivityThread.java:5525)
08-31 12:58:49.735: E/ActivityThread(7398):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2324)
08-31 12:58:49.735: E/ActivityThread(7398):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
08-31 12:58:49.735: E/ActivityThread(7398):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
08-31 12:58:49.735: E/ActivityThread(7398):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
08-31 12:58:49.735: E/ActivityThread(7398):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-31 12:58:49.735: E/ActivityThread(7398):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
08-31 12:58:49.735: E/ActivityThread(7398):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
08-31 12:58:49.735: E/ActivityThread(7398):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-31 12:58:49.735: E/ActivityThread(7398):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-31 12:58:49.735: E/ActivityThread(7398):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
08-31 12:58:49.735: E/ActivityThread(7398):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
08-31 12:58:49.735: E/ActivityThread(7398):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-31 12:58:49.735: E/ActivityThread(7398): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
08-31 12:58:49.735: E/ActivityThread(7398):     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc(Native Method)
08-31 12:58:49.735: E/ActivityThread(7398):     ... 15 more

Comment: Post your Code and LogCat crash report if any